# Custom Notification Sound does not play, default one plays every time

Tags: android, audio, push-notification, notifications

I know this question exists already, and I assure you I've read the answers, and none have helped me since my case is specific to the results of RingtonePreference

Below is the code I'm using for my push notification receiver service...
I get the ringtone preference from a RingtonePreference which is created by default when you go to create a Settings Activity in Android Studio.

The preference for the ringtones spit out a URI like this:
`content://media/internal/audio/media/38`

The problem is that no matter what sound a user selects in the preference, and even though I'm directly parsing a URI from this selection, the default sound of the phone plays every time!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

FYI: I've also tried setting the sound to `null` and then playing the ringtone manually using this code snippet:

```
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue)); 
ringtone.play();
```

But what happens is crazy.  The default ringtone STILL plays, AND the selected ringtone plays at the same time.  HELP!!!

Thanks!!!

```
public class GCMPushReceiverService extends GcmListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        Boolean doNotify = sp.getBoolean("notifications", true);
        Log.e("Notification", "Receiving a notification!");
        if(doNotify) {
            notifyUser(message, sp);
        }
        else{
            Log.e("Notification", "User has requested not to receive notifications");
        }
    }
    private void notifyUser(String message, SharedPreferences sp) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        int requestCode = 0;//Your request code
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri sound = null;
        String preferedRingtone = sp.getString("notifications_ringtone", "");

        Log.e("Notification", "Preparing to notify user!");

        if(preferedRingtone.equals("")) {
            Log.e("Notification", "User has no pref yet, use default");
            sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }
        else{
            sound = Uri.parse(preferedRingtone);
            Log.e("Notification", "Requested ringtone: " + sound.toString());
        }
        //Build notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentTitle("My App")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setSound(sound);

        Boolean vibratePref = sp.getBoolean("notifications_vibrate", true);
        if(vibratePref){
            Log.e("Notification", "User has requested vibrate!");
            noBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{0, 1000, 0, 1000});
        }
        else {
            Log.e("Notification", "User has requested no vibrate!");
            noBuilder.setVibrate(null);
        }
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, noBuilder.build()); //0 = ID of notification
    }
}
```